# Using network drive as alias in Apache 2.2 is not working

Tags: apache-2.2, network-share, httpd.conf, alias

OS is Windows 7

Appache is installed in "C:\AppServ\Apache2.2"

In **httpd.conf**

for documentroot

```
DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/myweb"
```

for alias:

```
alias /link/ "\\xxx.xx.xx.xx/myfolder/logs"
<Directory "\\xxx.xx.xx.xx/myfolder/logs"
```

The slashes MUST be "\" in the " < Directory" line in order for apache to start without error.

When i access this I'm getting 403 Forbidden, You don't have permission to access. And in the error.log of apache logs I'm getting "client denied by server configuration: C:/xxx.xx.xx.xx"

What have I tried:

- Different variations of slashes ( "/" , "\" ) in the alias and directory
- Use map drive instead of UNC

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Is there anything useful in Apache's error log?

Comment: "client denied by server configuration: C:/xxx.xx.xx.xx" only

Answer (score 0):

First you should not set your web files in C:/Program Files (x86)/

Then you need to set Apache user to your web folder

And for the sharing alias you need to set a network mapping instead of network addess